Look in data cluster in a row and fetch the first cell value of the row
I have a sheet where the first column has the names of people, next 4 columns have various dates. I want a function to check the cluster of dates and fetch the list of people allocated for a particular date.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


Set Autofilter for the sheet data
Record a macro when you set filtering for a specific date
Edit the recorded macro to use a variable for the date
Edit more; Add a dialog to ask for the date into that variable

All this should be easily google-able.
in the process you learn some basic VBA.

If I understand it correctly:
=TEXTJOIN(",",,REPT(A2:A6,B2:E6=G2))

